# Integral of weak derivative is finite

Tags: integration, weak-derivatives

I want to show that the integral over the unit ball of the weak derivative of $u(x)=|x|^{-\gamma}, 0< \gamma< \frac{n-p}{p}$ is finite, in order to show that the function is in $W^{1,p}$.

How can we find the waek derivative of $u(x)$ ?

I have tried the following:

$\langle \frac{\partial|x|^{-\gamma}}{\partial{x_i}}, \phi \rangle=-\langle |x|^{-\gamma}, \frac{\partial{\phi}}{\partial{x_i}} \rangle=- \int_{B(0,1)} |x|^{-\gamma} \frac{\partial{\phi}}{\partial{x_i}} dx$

Is it right so far? How could we continue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $u(x)=|x|^{-\gamma}$ defined for $x \in \Omega=B(0,1) \setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace$. Assuming temporarily wich $u$ is smooth, and can be differentiated pointwise with $\partial_{x_j} u= -\gamma x_j |x|^{-\gamma -2}$, and hence also $|\nabla u(x)|=|\gamma||x|^{-\gamma - 1}$. Recall a criterion of improper interation (with polar coordinate in $\mathbb{R}^n$), tells us that

$\displaystyle \int_{\Omega} \frac{1}{|x|^\gamma} dx < \infty$

if $\gamma < n$. In this sense we have $|\nabla u| \in L^1(\Omega)$ for $\gamma +1 < n$, and also $|\nabla u| \in L^p(\Omega)$ for $(\gamma +1)p < n$.
So we must assume $\gamma +1 < n$ and $(\gamma +1)p < n$.
Let $\varphi \in \mathcal{D}(\Omega)$ with $\mathrm{supp}(\varphi) \subset \Omega$, then $\varphi(x)=0$ on $\partial B(0,1)$, and with integration by parts we have

$\displaystyle \int_{\Omega} u \partial_{x_j} \varphi dx =-\int_{\Omega } \partial_{x_j}u \varphi dx + 0$

for the assumptions made. So that $\partial_{x_j} u$ is weak derivative of $u$, and $u \in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ if $u, |\nabla u| \in L^{p}(\Omega)$ for $(\gamma + 1)p < n$, i.e. for $\gamma < (n-p)/p$.

Comment: How do we get the following? $$$$

$\displaystyle \int_{\Omega \setminus B(0,\epsilon)} u \partial_{x_j} \varphi dx =-\int_{\Omega \setminus B(0,\epsilon)} \partial_{x_j}u \varphi dx + \int_{\partial B(0,\epsilon)} u \varphi \nu_j d \sigma$

Comment: I edited the answer, so nothing changes. The formula that you say essentially follows from the identity of Green, noting that $\partial (\Omega \setminus \overline{B}(0,\epsilon) ) ) =\partial \Omega \cup \partial B(0,\epsilon)$. There are just more things to consider, but in the end just choose the test function and no other ball. And note that the integrals that express the condition of weak derivative are well defined only with the assumptions that we have built, for the case of regular functions, this then extends to Sobolev functions.